# How to use MSBuild parameters in my C# code?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I know that I can use MSBuild parameters, like `$(SolutionDir)` for example to configure my build.

Now I want to use those parameters, inside my C# code.

I have a console application, and I want to get access to `$(SolutionDir)` folder. I know I can calculate it by writing some code, but I want to see if that's possible or not?

Comment: What exactly would you expect that "parameter" (macro) to contain when accessed from within the application? These are compile-time macros and won't really make much sense at runtime.

Comment: I consider it's bad practice that your application have hardcoded (even in compile time) metadata. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare task that will add new `.cs` file that will contain information you need. But it makes build more fragile, e.g. if there's no `.sln` file, string will be empty. Developers locale (en, ru, fr, etc.) could mess something. So be warned.

```xml
  <Target Name="EmbedSoltionPath" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(SolutionDir)' != '' and '$(SolutionDir)' != '*Undefined*'"><!-- avoid override with junk -->
    <PropertyGroup>
     <!-- %3B is semicolon (;)  -->
      <_PathTemplate>
namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal static class MyProps
    {
        internal const string SolutionDir = @"$(SolutionDir)"%3B
        internal const string LastBuildTime = @"$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)"%3B
    }
}
      </_PathTemplate>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="SolutionPath.cs" Lines="$(_PathTemplate)" WriteOnlyWhenDifferent="true" Overwrite="true" />
  </Target>
```